# GCC inline SSE code

Tags: c, gcc, vector, warnings, avx

Something bugs me regarding the vector extensions.

The document: `Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions Programming Reference`

States:

```
VPSRLD ymm1, ymm2, imm8
```

So I went ahead and:

```
__asm__ (
    "vpsrld %ymm0, %ymm0, $0x4"
);
```

*GCC 4.8.2-19ubuntu1* spits out:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `vpsrld'
```

Then after googling without any findings I started changing stuff around and this compiles:

```
__asm__ (
    "vpsrld  $0x4, %ymm0, %ymm0"
);
```

Anyone has any idea why anyone would change order compared to the reference guide?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Search for AT&T vs Intel syntax.

Comment: Have you considered using intrinsics instead? e.g. [_mm256_srli_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx2_srli_epi.htm)

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using intrinsics instead of raw asm - it will save a lot of time and pain.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because the GNU Assembler that's being used most often in the GCC toolchain uses the AT&T assembler syntax, which has a different operand order than the Intel one.

For example `mov eax, 5` in Intel format becomes `mov $5, %eax` in AT&T.

You can find some information about those two version on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language).

Comment: What's relevant for asm is the assembler you use (gas from binutils), not gcc directly.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my answer accordingly.